# Current working directory

Tags: c, traversal

I am currently building some code that traverses through directorys listing all files and paths and file sizes. I am now stuck with the final part of the traverse process which is the if statement to make the code go into any encountered directories.

```
do {
    char *filename = entry->d_name;
    stat(filename,&buffer);
    if (S_ISDIR(buffer.st_mode)) {
        name = entry->d_name;
        chdir(name);
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        listdir(name);     //THIS IS THE NAME OF THE FUNCTION THAT THIS SNIPPET IT FROM!
        chdir("..");
    }
    else
        printf("%s\t%d\n", entry->d_name,buffer.st_size);
```

Am so confused by trying to get it to cd into the directory that it encounters! ARGH!

Comment: Could you post the function `listdir()` in full?

Comment: @Ollie: press the edit button and paste the code into the question. It's unreadable in a comment box.

Comment: What problem are you having?  chdir should work with a relative directory.  However, you may be missing the initial chdir to the top level directory you are listing?

Comment: Here is the dropbox link!

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26148849/minix.c

Comment: Check return value from `chdir()`, if -1 check `errno` for failure reason.

Comment: idiotic question, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: `if (-1 == chdir(name)) { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno)); }` Add include directive `#include <errno.h>`.

Comment: no such file/directory... Im guessing it has something to do with my chdir () but i have no idea

Comment: Print `name` prior to the call to `chdir()` and check it appears sane.

Comment: ok so here is my prediction, that it is trying to change directory to say test for example and /path/to/test this is why im getting confused  as i dont know how to get the path of the file it is looking at.

EDIT: As i expected.. cw.o 9376
PATH  = `

Comment: Move the first chdir() *after* the if (idontlikeit) continue; statement.  Doing it too early makes you chdir("..") and madness ensues.

Comment: The error is now that is trying to cd to name (which == file name) which is why it wont move into the directory. How do i fix this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, when I executed, was `stat()` was failing.

This worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

void listdir(const char* const name);

int main(void)
{
    listdir(getenv("PWD"));
    return 0;
}

void listdir(const char* const name)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat buffer;
    char* path = 0;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;
    if (!(entry = readdir(dir)))
        return;

    do {
        path =
            malloc((strlen(name) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 2) * sizeof(char));
        sprintf(path, "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);

        if (-1 == stat(path,&buffer))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "stat(%s) failed: %s\n",
                path, strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (S_ISDIR(buffer.st_mode))
        {
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0)
            {
                listdir(path);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\t%d\n", path, buffer.st_size);
        }
        free(path);
    } while (entry = readdir(dir));
    closedir(dir);
}
```

EDIT:

Removed call to `chdir()` as realised it was superfluous. This does provide listing but does not do it using `chdir()`.

Comment: THANKS! now i just need to analyze every part that you have added so that i fully understand it! :-)

Comment: @Ollie, the main difference is it constructs the absolute path to each file/directory.

Comment: cheers man! Thank you so much! I just hope that this post doesn't get back to me as plagiarism, not that im going to copy and paste this and then continue working from it

Comment: @Ollie You *chose* to post the link to your `.c` file. Just don't plagiarize code and you won't get in trouble.

Comment: haha what i meant was, i hope that they dont see that file and think that i took it off here, obviously i havent seeing as i wrote it...

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `lstat`. Second, with your `chdir(name)` call, you actually *do* go up into parent direectories (when name=".."), but never go back down.

Comment: to go back down would be chdir(".")?

Comment: @Ollie, no that will have no effect. Removing the `chdir(name)` prior to the `strcmp()` checks should fix this as described by jorgensen.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help. It still isnt working for me despite making the above changes, I feel like i may have coded this incredibly wrong as it seems tolist files until it find the first directory and then just dies.

Comment: following those changes, all it does now is display the first file in the folder

Answer (score 0):

The problems lie in this code:

```
if (S_ISDIR(buffer.st_mode)) {
    name = entry->d_name;
    chdir(name);
    if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
        continue;
    listdir(name);     //THIS IS THE NAME OF THE FUNCTION THAT THIS SNIPPET IT FROM!
    chdir("..");
}
```

This is embedded in a do-while loop, but you don't show us how the directory entry is read.

The `strcmp()` conditions should be applied to the current directory before doing a `chdir()`; that is a 'dangerous' operation.  When you're sure that you need to process the directory, then you can do `chdir()`, open a new directory stream, and process entries from the new stream - which is probably a recursive call, and then `chdir()` back again.  Your jump after you've done `chdir(..)` (because you didn't check for `..` before doing the `chdir(name)`) is going to wreak havoc on things.

You should look up `fchdir()` which might be better for the purpose of getting back to where you started.

Comment: Here is the whole code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26148849/minix.c I will look into those things you said things now

Comment: The issue i am having is that the chdir is chdir(<FILENAME>), would it not have to be chdir(</path/to/FILENAME>) (where filename the second time is the name of a directory)?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the full path name, though obviously that works.  If you do `chdir(name)` where name is the entry read from the current directory, it will take you down one directory level - subject to the name not being a symlink.  (They grotesquely complicate things; watch out for cycles in directories with symlinks.)