# A c++ program to count word

Tags: c++

> Write a program that prompts the user to input the name of a text file and then outputs the number of words in the file. You can consider a “word” to be any text that is surrounded by whitespace (for example, a space, carriage return, newline, etc.) or borders the beginning or end of the file.

During compiling of the program, when I input the [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnjRV.png) which I put some words inside, I keep getting "0 word" for the output. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const string filename="words.txt";
const string PUNC=".?!,;";

int main()
{  
int numWords, numChars;
string word;

cout << "Enter filename:" << endl;
std::string filename;
cin >> filename;

ifstream in_stream;
in_stream.open(filename.c_str());

if(in_stream)
{
    int numWords=0, numChars=0;
    string word;
}

cout<< fixed << setprecision(0);

 while(in_stream >> word)
{
    ++numWords;
    int len=word.size();

    if(PUNC.find(word[len-1])!=string::npos)
        word.erase(len-1);
    numChars+=word.size();


}

in_stream.close();

cout << "This is my \"slash\" <--" << endl; 
if(numWords<=1)
{
cout << "There is " << numWords << " word in the file " << filename << "." << endl;
}

else{
    cout << "There are " << numWords << " words in the file " << filename << "." << endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?"_ Probably not without seeing your code and input? Show a [MCVE] in your question please.

Comment: *"Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?"* It has a bug, or you misused it. For more info, MCVE as @πάνταῥεῖ said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C program to count total words in an input file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506556/c-program-to-count-total-words-in-an-input-file)

Comment: Are you sure the file path is correct?

Comment: @DimChtz: I think so. I will post an image of the file. You can take a look for it.

Comment: This is one way you could check the file was opened `if(!if_stream.fail())`

Comment: @DarrenPan -- Given the requirements, your attempt is way too complicated with `erase` calls and such.  This shouldn't be anything more than 5 or so lines of code **if** you're actually allowed to use the proper C++ idioms (such as `std::istringstream`).

Comment: @FirstStep: it shows me that the file does not open

Comment: @PailMcKenzie: how can I make some changes?

Comment: @DarrenPan What's the path you enter?

Comment: Where is your file? If it is on the desktop, you need to put the whole path starting from `c:`like this: `in_stream.open("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\" + FileName.c_str())`. Or move your file to the solution folder, where your `.exe` is located

Comment: @DimChtz: Sorry! I am not very understand what you are asking.

Comment: @DarrenPan `cin >> filename;` Here you type the path of the file. What did you type?

Comment: @FirstStep: I see what you are saying. I put the file into the right place now.  However, my output is like " Hello           World          There are 2 words in the file words.txt.", my expect output is just "There are 2 words in the file words.txt." Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @DarrenPan Maybe because of this `cout << ' ' << left << setw(15) << word;`? What is left?

Comment: Yes. Your code works exactly how wrote it: `cout << ' ' << left << setw(15) << word;`

Comment: You can not have spaces in your file path as `cin >> filename; ` will read only to first space.

Comment: @FirstStep: OK! I fixed it.  I still have one more question: I want the output: "There are 2 words in the file "words.txt"." but my output is  "There are 2 words in the file words.txt.".  I don't know how to put the (" ") to the words.txt.

Comment: Add it within the code and put the slash before it like this: `"There are 2 words in the file \"words.txt\""`

Comment: @FirstStep: I am not sure where to add.

Comment: Darren, use this in your code and see how it gets displayed then you will understand: `cout <<"This is my slash >\" but it does not appear and it allows the \" to be compiled and displayed AS IT IS";` put this statement in your code and execute it then look at the console and see the difference

Comment: @FirstStep: add in which line?

Comment: See the new update on my answer

Comment: @FirstStep: I added it, but the compiler said this is an error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @FirstStep: I put it in mu code. May be you can take a look to see whether I put in the right place or not.

Comment: I don't see that you added it in your code

Comment: FWIW, the "if (instream)" block defines **new** variables, it does not initialize the variables declared outside the block.

Comment: I corrected your line with the "slash". Try to compile that now. To put a " in a string, you must use \" instead.

Comment: @DarrenPan [See this](http://ideone.com/ISY4Wb).  The only difference is that the "file" is `cin` instead of a data file.  Otherwise, the code that reads a line and uses `istringstream` is all that's needed to count the words.

Comment: So you are not going to flag your question as solved by my answer?

Comment: @FirstStep: I don't know how to flag.

Comment: There is a "green check" beside the answer, on the left. Click it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is on the desktop, you need to put the whole path starting from `c:` like this: `in_stream.open("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\" + FileName.c_str())`. Or move your file to the solution folder, where your **.exe** is located.

**EDIT:**

This is how you display it:

```
if(numWords<=1)
{
cout << "There is " << numWords << " word in the file \"" << filename << "\"." << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "There are " << numWords << " words in the file \"" << filename << "\"." << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DarrenPan Good job :) glad we were able to help. Feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me!!

It outputs a lot more than it needs to but the core of the code is correct (though not very nicely written).

#### Build and Run

```
> cat data.txt
 1 2 3
> g++ -std=c++14 -o xx xx.cpp
> ./xx
Enter filename:
data.txt
 1               2               3              There are 3 words in the file data.txt.
```

#### Possible Problem

The problem looks like it is the name of the file you input not matching the file name. This includes the directory. When an application runs it has a working directory. If you specify a relative file name then the file name is relative to this directory (current working directory).

See: [Current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8460166/14065)

Solutions.

1. Work out the correct relative path to your file from the current working directory.
2. Move your data file to the current working directory.
3. Specify an absolute path

Comment: OK! I fixed it. I still have one more question: I want the output: "There are 2 words in the file "words.txt"." but my output is "There are 2 words in the file words.txt.". I don't know how to put the (" ") to the words.txt.

Comment: @DarrenPan: There are a couple of ways to do this. But the simplest is to just simply escape the `"` character. To do that proceed it with a backslash \\ . So the code would be: `std::cout << "There are 2 words in the file \" " << filename << "\"\n";`

Comment: Now you have it working. Ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com how to make it better.